# Linked cursorbar over subplots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In the picture below i placed two sub plots with two cursorbar using:

```
 figure;
 t=0:.01:7;
 subplot(2,1,1)
 hp1=plot(t,sin(t));
 hCursorbar1 = graphics.cursorbar(hp1); drawnow
 subplot(2,1,2)
 hp2=plot(t,cos(t));
 hCursorbar2 = graphics.cursorbar(hp2); drawnow
```

At present, when I move cursorbar in one if the subpolts, it does not have an influence on the other cursorbar in the other subplot.

I would like to link between the two cursorbar, in such a way, that when i move one of the cursorbar (right\left), it will move the other cursorbar on the other subplot as well.

Is it possible?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

```
lis1=addlistener ( hCursorbar1,'Location','PostSet', ...
            @(~,~)set(hCursorbar1,'Location',hCursorbar2.Location));
lis1=addlistener ( hCursorbar2,'Location','PostSet', ...
            @(~,~)set(hCursorbar2,'Location',hCursorbar1.Location));
```

cf: [cursorbar.m fileexchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49612-cursorbar/content/Cursorbar/cursorbar.m)  & [cursorbar undocomentedmatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-cursorbar-object)

Hoping this will help =)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Curretly i have 2011b Matlab. I hope that it will soon change to R2015b.